# Test osgi with Pax Exam

Tags: osgi, pax-exam

Now I am using Pax Exam to test OSGI ,but when i create a osgi helloworld project，how should
i use PaxExam to create a junit test project to test helloworld osgi? Thanks!

Comment: I have a minimal example at https://github.com/bdelacretaz/paxexam-minimal-example based on the tutorial at https://github.com/tonit/Learn-PaxExam/tree/master/lesson-junit

Comment: Have you read http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxexam/Getting+Started+with+OSGi+Tests?

Comment: You may find http://www.javabeat.net/2011/11/how-to-test-osgi-applications helpful.

Comment: OK,above is helpful,thanks

Comment: I think the PAX exam documentation is very sparse especially for someone new to it, like myself and trying to work out just which of the seemingly numerous PAX bundles are required just to try out a simple 'HelloWorld' test.